# live streaming for the text/drawing

Tags: ipad, drawing, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I have an iPad app which has a white board. what ever we write/draw anything over there.
Whatever I do on the app, should be viewable from some website (Live streaming).

Is there any library available to get above task.

Comment: have you recorded that video...

Comment: this is possible i can help you but please explain what you did

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use HLS and instead send only delta updates. I expect that your whiteboard is mostly static, and using h.264 video compression doesn't really make sense in that case. It will reduce the image quality and take a very large amount of bandwidth.